# How would I declare an array of function pointers in C?

Tags: c, declaration, type-declaration

How would I declare `a` as a array of 4 pointers to functions with no parameters and which return `void`? The pointers originally point to functions with names: `insert`, `search`, `update`, and `print`.

This is the closest I can get to the declaration:

`void (*a[4]) () {insert,search,update,print}`

Comment: You might want to start with `typedef void (*func)(void);` and then create an array of `func`.

Answer (score 4):

It's so much more readable using a typedef when dealing with function pointers.

```c
typedef void (*MyFuncPtr)( void );

MyFuncPtr a[] = { insert, search, update, print };
```

Note that no arguments is denoted using `(void)`, not `()`.

Note that while `[4]` is ok, `[]` is sufficient here.

Without, it would be

```c
void (*a[])( void ) = { insert, search, update, print };
```

Answer (score 2):

In ISO C18, the line

```
void (*a[4]) ();
```

will declare an array of 4 elements in which each element is a pointer to a function returning `void` that takes an unspecified number of arguments. If you want to specify that the functions to take no arguments, then you must write `(void)` instead of `()`:

```
void (*a[4])(void);
```

However, in the upcoming ISO C23, this is no longer necessary, as specifying a function with an unspecified number of arguments is no longer possible (except for variadic functions). In C23, it is therefore sufficient to write `()` instead of `(void)`. This also applies to ISO C++.

Also, if you want to initialize the array, you must use `=`, like this:

```
void (*a[4])(void) = {insert,search,update,print};
```

In C++, the `=` is not necessary during initialization, but it is necessary in C (both in C18 and C23).

Comment: So the C++ counterpart would be same as OP's?

Comment: @Haris: Yes, OP's original code is correct in modern C++.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the assignment operator. Change it to:

```
// Thee may dropeth the 4, shouldst thee so wanteth.
void (*a[4])(void) = { insert , search , update , print };
```

Note that empty brackets specify an unspecified number of arguments (not necessarily 0). If that's not what you want, specify `void`.

Answer (score 0):

To add a more step-by-step way of thinking about this, a good way to think about complex C declarations is that they are **declared** the same way they are **used**. So ask yourself how you would use (index and call) an array of function pointers?

- First we would index `a[]`
- Then dereference the function pointer to obtain a function `*a[]`
- And then we would call `(*a[])()`

Now to turn this into a declaration:

- Since the functions return `void` and take no arguments the declaration is `void` and add `void` to the parameters bringing us to `void (*a[])(void);`
- Finally add an initializer list `= {}` as we would a normal array

This leaves us with:

```
void (*a[])(void) = {insert, search, update, print};
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, one can use a popular `typeof` extension (a feature in C23) for convenient and readable syntax.

```
typeof(void(void)) * a[] = {...};
```

The `a` is an array of pointers to `void(void)` function.

Answer (score 0):

Developers usually not using function pointers. These reasons are:

- A switch statement, so letting the compiler do the work is preferable.
- Function pointers are dangerous.
- Function pointers are too difficult to code and maintain.
  but you can use:

  ```
  return_type (*function_array[4])(argument_list);
  ```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should probably read this:  https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/filesystems/vfs.html  Every Linux filesystem is implemented using function pointers.  Other OSes are the same.  SIgnal handlers in C are installed via a function pointer.  Multithreading is implemented using function pointers.  Sorting such as standard C `qsort()` uses function pointers.  [Jump tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table#Jump_table_example_in_C) in C use function pointers, and can make for easy-to-maintain code.